# UWP C# - Access mobile phone files

Tags: c#, mobile, uwp, access-denied

I am writing some kind of file synchronisation UWP program.  This app will run on a Windows desktop and synchronize files to my mobile device, an android phone.  My phone is plugged on my dev PC on the USB port and is seen as "My Device" in file explorer.  From file explorer, I can access the main storage of my phone and create a file.

In my app manifest, I added a file type association declaration for files with extension ".profile".

When my application try to create the profile file "myprofile.profile" with the following code, it fails with a COMException 0x80004005 who correspond to an access denied error.  The profileDevice variable is of type StorageDevice.

```
StorageFile profileFile = await profileDevice.RootFolder.CreateFileAsync("myProfile.profile", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

Any idea if what I want to do is possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Before synchronize files to removable storage. you need declare the specific file type. if your file type is **.txt**, you need add type extension name to **File Type Associations** capability.

[image]

For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-filetypeassociation)

Please note, because the file transfer protocol is MTP, so you could not use `CreateFileAsync` method. please try to use `CopyAsync` method and copy the file from your computer to your phone.

```
StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices; 
StorageFolder sdCard = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

if (sdCard != null)
{
    var rootFolder = await sdCard.GetFoldersAsync();
    var folder = rootFolder[0];
    var picker = new FileOpenPicker
    {
        FileTypeFilter = { ".jpg", ".png", ".gif", ".txt" },
        SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
    };
    var sourceFile = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (sourceFile != null)
    {
        var newfile = await sourceFile.CopyAsync(folder, sourceFile.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    }
}
else
{
    // No SD card is present.
}
```

Comment: As I said, I already created the file type in the manifest.  Also, yes, this is a sync app who will ultimately copy files.  But what I describe as my problem is a file *creation*.  I still need to create a profile file to keep metadata for the device so it could sync to any PC who have my app installed.

Comment: Yep, I think the better way is you could create the profile file in your app's local folder then copy to mobile phone.

Comment: This is not an option.  The goal is to be able to plug the mobile device on any PC who have this file and the profile will be executed.  I have seen something about mtp (media transfer protocol), I will look to see if this will do the job.